# UIActionSheet block view controller dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiactionsheet, ios8.1

When in my View controller I touch on a button launch this simple code

```
- (IBAction)tapOnButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *act = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"aa" destructiveButtonTitle:@"bb" otherButtonTitles:@"cc", nil];
    [act showFromRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100) inView:self.view animated:YES];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {

    }
}
```

I get a Actionsheet on screen, tap on any button of the Actionsheet and this closes.

When I run dismiss my viewcontroller is not performed dealloc .
If you do not touch the button and do not open the actionsheet the dealloc works .

is a big enough problem. Someone 's going on?

i'm on ios 8.1.3

Comment: Please replace the screenshot of your code with the actual text of the code so people can read it.

Comment: Is there any problem if you run the code on a device (or simulator) with iOS 7?

Comment: I am having the same issue in iOS 8.1. Maybe this is an iOS 8 bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am experiencing the same problem using the deprecated UIActionSheet in iOS 8 iPad. Using iPhone (iOS 7 and iOS 8) and iOS 7 iPad, the problem cannot be reproduced.

The only solution right now that I have tested to be working is to use UIAlertController to present action sheets in iOS 8. If you use UIAlertController, the View Controller gets deallocated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely some references are retained to the view controller - hence it is not being deallocated.

Please try setting the delegate explicitly to nil in the delegate method like below:

```
- (IBAction)tapOnButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *act = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"aa" destructiveButtonTitle:@"bb" otherButtonTitles:@"cc", nil];
    [act showFromRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100) inView:self.view animated:YES];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {

    }
    actionSheet.delegate = nil
}
```

Comment: the code has been written about ios7 , should review all the application . But if I do not put the delegates how do I perform the action when the user taps a button? Also I have always seen him use so actionsheet , seems something has changed

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code in the question and nothing about that code should be causing a reference cycle. People have been using similar code since iOS 2.0 without issue.

Comment: You can try setting the actionsheet to nil in the delegate methods for the actions to make sure there will be no reference cycles

Comment: There is no reason at all to create an ivar for the action sheet. Simply do `actionSheet.delegate = nil;` in the delegate method.

Comment: This does not work for me in iOS 8 iPad. The View controller still does not get deallocated.